# Black Hole and gained Mass

Tags: black-holes

This question is the continuous of this : [Black Hole Surface Area-Mass Equation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/441490/black-hole-surface-area-mass-equation/441762?noredirect=1#comment995575_441762)

Let us suppose a black hole with mass M and Surface are A, then using the schwarzhild radius equation we can derive that

$$dM/dt=\alpha \frac {1} {\sqrt{A}} \frac {dA}{dt}~~~~Eq.1$$
$$dA/dt=\beta M \frac {dM}{dt}~~~~Eq.2$$

Now let us think a gas cloud that surrounds the black hole. The mass of this gas $m$ and denisty $p_m$

[image]

The volume of the painted side is $V=4\pi r^2dr$ and in terms of the surface area, the mass of the gass can be described as

$$dm=Ap_mdr$$

Now I was thinking to put this term into the Equation 1. So I thought that we can say $dM/dt=dm$ since the gained mass by the black hole will be $m$. But its clear that units dont match. So how can I connect these equations ?

Comment: If the hole swallows the gas, then its mass increases by the mass of the gas: $dM=dm$.

Comment: I never thought that way...